# Advantages to a Fat Jar vs an application bundle in Gradle

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I've been using gradle for a while now and love the application plugin which allows you to create dist bundles that contain command line runners for you so you don't have to worry about setting up the classpath etc.

Recently I've seen several projects (i.e. dropwizard) suggest using fat jar files.  With the dist bundles in gradle I don't really see the need to create fat jar files.

Is there something that I'm missing about fat jar files?

Comment: What do you mean about "setting up the classpath"? The point of an uber jar is that it _is_ the classpath. Even without bundling everything together, the classpath can be defined in the manifest file.

Comment: I mean that when gradle creates the bundle for you (./gradlew distTar), the command line runner takes care of making sure that all your dependencies are on the classpath.

Comment: IMO both solutions do pretty much the same. I suppose that You can just pick what works better for You, jar or script.

Comment: I agree that they do pretty much the same.  I was just curious if there was a big reason why there are several projects out there that suggest using fat jars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fat Jar doesn't require an unzip step, and makes it easier to start the application without a shell script (because no class path needs to be set). Having just a single file to care about can simplify automation. Also other build tools do not provide an out-of-the-box way to create an application distribution.